# How to improve performance of  multiple rails applications with nginx running on a single core 378mb VPS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, vps

I have a VPS which is hosting (currently) 5 different rails applications, all with different domains. To make them work I've added one server {} listener per app in my nginx config file. I've left everything else as default, for instance there's only one nginx worker process.
Concurrently, I also have 2 rails workers for one of the apps.

Now, this works as is, but performances are low, in particular speed. How could I make my apps quicker by adhering to my constraints?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify "low performance" ? Are you running out memory. Is the load high? Are all the available CPUs being put to use? Is there a  database behind the app? Which one? Is it on the same machine?

Comment: By low performance I mean very high loading times. The loading times seem especially high when switching from one app to the other, but that's not necessarily consistent. Everything is on the same machine, with one core and 378mb of ram. They all run their own Mysql db.

Comment: What does the memory situation look like? How much of the 378mb is being used? How much swap in use? When it is slowly switching from one app to other, how high is the load on the server, according to 'top' ?

Comment: In top, I see 8 instances of ruby. One has 24 %MEM, another 15. Virtual memory goes up to 927m for the biggest instance. CPU gets bursts of max 50% when switching. RAM: 330mb used, 35mb free. Swap: 558mb used, 490mb free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are deep into swap. The slowness you experiencing switching apps is the system loading the requested app from swap into physical memory.

To address this, you can observe who is hogging the memory (also using 'top'), and address that. It's possible you'll find some things to tune, but also quite possible you'll find that you are near the physical limits of what's possible without significant architectural changes.

If your time is worth much, your best course of action will be to upgrade to an instance with at least a 1GB of memory, because you are already using nearly that much.

Comment: Thanks Mark, let check which of the apps is eating the memory.

Comment: I'm using a regular version of Ruby, I'm reading that REE could help reducing memory usage, I might try installing it and see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

The nginx "worker_processes" should be set to the number of cores that you have available to work with. You mentioned you had it set to 1. Do you have more cores than that?

Comment: I only have one core indeed, it's basically the smallest VPS I coult get :)